# Custom keypair with the Ledger Nano S

Tags: xlm, ledger-nano

Generating a vanity address with a custom suffix is easy (from a custom made script) but is it possible to use the generated keypair with the Ledger Nano S?

If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generating a vanity address is trial and error process. You generate key pairs until you find a public key with a prefix you want.

You can apply the same method here. For example, in Go use [`derivation`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stellar/go/exp/crypto/derivation) package and generate random mnemonic seeds as long as the *primary* account (`m/44'/148'/0'`) has a public key with the searched prefix:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"

  "github.com/bartekn/go-bip39"
  "github.com/stellar/go/exp/crypto/derivation"
  "github.com/stellar/go/keypair"
)

const EntropySize = 256
const Prefix = "GABC"

func main() {
  for {
    entropy, err := bip39.NewEntropy(EntropySize)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    mnemonic, err := bip39.NewMnemonic(entropy)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    seed, err := bip39.NewSeedWithErrorChecking(mnemonic, "")
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    key, err := derivation.DeriveForPath(derivation.StellarPrimaryAccountPath, seed)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    kp, err := keypair.FromRawSeed(key.RawSeed())
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    if strings.HasPrefix(kp.Address(), Prefix) {
      fmt.Println(mnemonic)
      fmt.Println(kp.Address())
      fmt.Println(kp.Seed())
      break
    }
  }
}
```

---

While it's technically possible, I strongly discourage you to do it. Generating cryptographic keys outside Ledger device can be less secure.

---

**EDIT** I realized that you asked about suffix, not prefix. To achieve this we need a small modification to the script:

- Change `Prefix` const to `Suffix`
- Change `strings.HasPrefix(kp.Address(), Prefix)` to `strings.HasSuffix(kp.Address(), Suffix)`

Comment: This does not reply to my question. I asked if it was possible to use the generated seed on a hardware wallet such as the Ledger Nano S.

Comment: It does answer your question. You can import the mnemonic seed found by a script above into Ledger (using recovery feature).

Comment: I see, but if I already have the address. What are the steps to add it into the device?

Comment: You can't add vanity address to previously generated master keys on the Ledger. The only way is to generate a new keys (ex. using the script above) and use Ledger recovery function to import new keys.